# Go Syntax and interface as parameter to function

Tags: syntax, interface, go

I am new to Go programming language and recently encountered the following code:

```
func (rec *ContactRecord) Less(other interface{}) bool {
  return rec.sortKey.Less(other.(*ContactRecord).sortKey);
}
```

However, I do not understand  the meaning behind the function signature. It accepts an interface as a parameter. Could you please explain me how this works ? Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Go uses interfaces for generalization of types. So if you want a function that takes a specific interface
you write

```
func MyFunction(t SomeInterface) {...}
```

Every type that satisfies `SomeInterface` can be passed to `MyFunction`.

Now, `SomeInterface` can look like this:

```
type SomeInterface interface {
    SomeFunction()
}
```

To satisfy `SomeInterface`, the type implementing it must implement `SomeFunction()`.

If you, however, require an empty interface (`interface{}`) the object does not need to
implement any method to be passed to the function:

```
func MyFunction(t interface{}) { ... }
```

This function above will take every type as [all types implement the empty interface](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

#### Getting the type back

Now that you can have every possible type, the question is how to get the type back that
was actually put in before. The empty interface does not provide any methods, thus you
can't call anything on such a value.

For this you need type assertions: let the runtime check whether there is type X in value Y and
convert it to that type if so.

Example:

```
func MyFunction(t interface{}) {
    v, ok := t.(SomeConcreteType)
    // ...
}
```

In this example the input parameter `t` is asserted to be of type `SomeConcreteType`. If `t`
is in fact of type `SomeConcreteType`, `v` will hold the instance of that type and `ok` will
be true. Otherwise, `ok` will be false. See [the spec on type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) for details.

Comment: interesting, this helped me on another problem, I forgot the {} after the interface and was getting a "missing function body" compile error, I liked to never figure it out!

Answer (score 6):

An `interface` variable can hold values of any type that provides methods with the signatures from the interface declaration.  Since `interface{}` doesn't specify any methods, such a variable can store values of any type.

The method then goes on to use a type assertion to check that `other` is actually a `*ContactRecord` value (it will panic otherwise).

You might then ask why the method isn't declared as taking a `*ContactRecord` argument then.  The most likely reason is so that the `*ContactRecord` type implements some interface with a `Less` method with that signature.